# Uppercase validation rule

Tags: validation-rule, compile-error

I have a text field, NAV_Customer_ID, that is been active in our org for years now.  I am trying to put in a validation rule that this now has to be in all caps, but I am getting an error message on syntax (Error: Field NAV_Customer_ID does not exist. Check spelling.)

NAV_Customer_ID__c  <>  UPPER(NAV_Customer_ID)

Answer (score 1):

NAV_Customer_ID__c <> UPPER( NAV_Customer_ID__c )

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
NAV_Customer_ID__c <> UPPER(NAV_Customer_ID__c)
```

The field name is incorrect while passing it to the UPPER function